# Kubernetes ingress hsts not enabled

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, https, kubernetes-ingress, hsts

my current ingress configuration is:

```
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "app-ingress"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "app-external-ip"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "example.app"
      secretName: "app-tls"
  rules:
    - host: "example.app"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: "Prefix"
            backend:
              service:
                name: "app-service"
                port:
                  number: 80
```

now i struggle with not HSTS enabled. I can enter example.app with http and https protocol, but i want to strict it to https only. I tried:

- using nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true" - still http available
- using kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false" - creates google managed certificate (im using self signed one app-tls) which makes ssl cert error in browser.
  I'm pretty sure second one should be the option and i'm doing something wrong or misconfigure something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ingress class is **GCE** and might be using the **GCE** **ingress** so **Nginx** **annotation** should not work.

So you have to create the

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-frontend-config
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
    responseCodeName: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
```

Read more at : [Doc ref](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#https_redirect)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that's the solution for me. I've tried to manuallyremove http frontend rule, but console didnt allow me to, but applying this configuration did work. Now http requests are beeing redirect to https